# Getting classcast exception with "mvn clean" with Java 8

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I am getting below exception when running the `mvn clean` command from command prompt, using Java 8.

Previously I used Java 6, but I did not get this type of exception.

```
constituent[0]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/aether-api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[1]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/guava-18.0.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/guice-4.0-no_aop.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-compat-3.3.9.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-core-3.3.9.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-plugin-api-3.3.9.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-settings-3.3.9.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/maven-settings-builder-3.3.9.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.2.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.2.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/wagon-file-2.10.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/wagon-http-2.10-shaded.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/wagon-http-shared-2.10.jar
constituent[41]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../lib/wagon-provider-api-2.10.jar
constituent[42]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/../conf/logging/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/sisu/inject/MutableBeanLocator
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:545)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:281)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.sisu.inject.MutableBeanLocator
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Check what version of maven compiler plugin you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the file that it is saying is not there.
Is is present at the desired place?

Comment: Yes i saw that this class is present in the jar

org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.m3.jar


and this jar is present in the below file location


C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.2.jar

still getting the error

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved, at present I am using 3.3.9, now I tried with 3.3.3 Maven and it is fine and working.

Thanks to every one who helped me.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if the issue is resolved.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/302176

Comment: Bravo, are you familiar with how to accept answers here? If an answer particularly solved the problem, find the adjacent "tick" icon, and click it so it turns green. Let me know when you have done this please, so I can undownvote - I can be pinged at `@halfer`.